# Error " You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits " When i want Edit

Tags: support

When i want Edit one Post, This Error Displayed :

> **You are temporarily banned from suggesting edits**

So, What can i do for Unban || Day Or time limit for Unban ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accounts are temporarily blocked from suggesting edits if [too many of their suggested edits are rejected by reviewers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337/150283). The block lasts for 7 days, and the error message used to tell you how many days were left, but I do not know if it still does.

In any case, your account will be allowed to suggest edits once again in 5 more days. In the meantime, I would recommend that you take a look at [some of your recent edits](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/82964/m4t?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and note the reasons given for the ones that were rejected.

As specific guidance, the problematic edits that I see appear to:

- Add only bold/italics/other formatting to the post without attempting to fix much else. In some cases, this formatting appeared over-used as well, in my opinion. Examples would include using `code formatting` to emphasize `keywords`. That's not really its intended use, and inline formatting is generally best used sparingly.
- Add sign-offs like "Thanks in advance!" that were not previously present in the post. This is actually [the opposite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/150283) of our general posting guidelines, and is typically regarded as unnecessary or "noisy". Such taglines are frequently subject to removal from posts during a larger edit, in fact.